# How to rotate the direction of the curve extrusion by 90 degrees

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm modeling a ribbon out of a curve to put on a present model.

I'm using the extrude feature to form the actual ribbon.

[image]

The issue, is that the curve is tilted the wrong way.

[image]

How can I rotate the direction of the curve extrusion by 90 degrees?

Comment: I thought for sure I saw a question just like this in the past day or so, let me check.

Comment: @HATMAN Could that have been me in chat a few days ago?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not sure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is done using the **tilt** feature.

In the curve edit mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. Then simply type in 90 to tilt it by 90 degrees.

[image]